# gwt - cannot create unit test for class that uses HTMLPanel

Tags: java, unit-testing, gwt, testing, mockito

I have util class with one method:

```
 public static void setStyleForWidgetLayout(HTMLPanel panel, int rowQuantity) {
```

Which for each Widget in HTMLPannel assign widgth depends on number of widgets and rows.
It is very simple switch.

I want to test this method but when i create test with normal JUnit test case i recieve error on creating HTMLPanel.

```
 Caused by: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: ERROR: GWT.create() is only usable in client code!  It cannot be called, for example, from server code.  If you are running a unit test, check that your test case extends GWTTestCase and that GWT.create() is not called from within an initializer or constructor.
```

Next I tried to extend GWTTestCase but it requires to implement getModuleName() but i dont have any particular module because the class I test is just util class

Ok, I thought, lets mock it. I used mockito, but the errror occured, same as from previous code section.

Than I found class GwtTestWithMockito and tried to run this and again I recieved error.

```
com.googlecode.gwt.test.exceptions.GwtTestConfigurationException: No declared module. Did you forget to add your own META-INF/gwt-test-utils.properties file with a 'gwt-module' property in the test classpath?
```

I added @GWTModule and this META-INF/gwt-test-util.properties. And experimented with different configurations. I tried existing module names and not existing ones but still i recieve error above.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid you have to use GWTTestCase. Your module name is the name of your module XML file.

Sometimes you have to add your Panel to the root panel, I generally do this just to be on the safe side.

Comment: i dont have XML module file because the class i want to test isnt module just utils :)

Comment: you can still have a module for testing etc... otherwise the compiler doesn't know what to do. https://github.com/salk31/RedQueryBuilder/blob/master/redquerybuilder-core/src/main/java/com/redspr/redquerybuilder/core/RedQueryBuilderCore.gwt.xml is not an end usable module in itself but still is declared as a module. If you look at the GWT sdk it has lots of sub modules so you can pick and choose what you want. You will probably want a module to include into end usages of the code.